# How to do a Twitter Bootstrap Intro

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to make a one paged layout website. When the user joins the page it has a full screen div/ jumbotron then you can scroll down. I am trying to make something very similar to the element on www.freedom.tm.

I have seen this used all over the place, all help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Start your template with:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! When you add an anchor link, will jQuery automatically add a smooth transition?

Comment: your css "body,html{overflow:hidden}" is breaking the scrolling.

Comment: Yes. If you will use animate like in this example i created for you http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/q92mq/